# Factory_bot can't create "project" factory

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I am writing several factories within a project I am mantaining. All of them work except for the `project` factory.

When I run the factory in rails console I get the following error

```
FactoryBot.create(:project)
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for :project:Symbol from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.6/gems/factory_bot-4.11.1/lib/factory_bot/declaration/implicit.rb:11:in `=='
```

It seems that somehow, factory_bot can't convert the symbol :project into its Project class.

Ruby version is 2.3.6. Factory_bot is 4.11.1. Factory_bot_rails is 4.11.1 as well.

This is my project factory file:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project do
    name                              { Faker::Company.name }
    product_type                      { Faker::Number.between(0, 1) }
    sale_type                         { Faker::Number.between(0, 1) }
    description                       { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    street                            { Faker::Address.street_name }
    neighborhood                      { Faker::Address.community }
    zip_code                          { Faker::Address.zip }
    country                           { Faker::Address.country_code }
    state                             { Faker::Address.state_abbr }
    city                              { Faker::Address.city }
    town                              { Faker::Address.city }
    logo                              { Faker::Company.logo }
    cover                             { Faker::Company.logo }
    send_from_email                   { Faker::Internet.email }
    parking_lot_cost                  { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    warehouse_m2_cost                 { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    association :client, factory: user
    inventory_dimension_value         { Faker::Number.digit }
    total_m2                          { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    sales_volume_total                { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    total_units                       { Faker::Number.digit }
    current_m2_sold                   { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    sales_volume_current_sold         { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    current_units_sold                { Faker::Number.digit }
    sales_volume_to_sell              { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    next_list_acum                    { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    from_email                        { Faker::Internet.email }
    saved_next_list_acum              { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    settings_show_distributions_cols  { Faker::Boolean.boolean }
    settings_price_list_v2_enabled    { Faker::Boolean.boolean }
    api_token                         { Faker::Lorem.word }
  end
end
```

*Edit:* this is the database schema for the projects table

```
                                                   Table "public.projects"                                                    
              Column              |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
----------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id                               | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('projects_id_seq'::regclass) 
 name                             | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 product_type                     | integer                     |           |          |                                      
 sale_type                        | integer                     |           |          |                                      
 description                      | text                        |           |          |                                      
 street                           | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 neighborhood                     | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 zip_code                         | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 country                          | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 state                            | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 city                             | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 town                             | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 logo                             | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 cover                            | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 send_from_email                  | text                        |           |          |                                      
 parking_lot_cost                 | double precision            |           |          | 0.0                                  
 warehouse_m2_cost                | double precision            |           |          | 0.0                                  
 created_at                       | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |                                      
 updated_at                       | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |                                      
 client_id                        | integer                     |           |          |                                      
 inventory_dimension_value        | integer                     |           |          |                                      
 total_m2                         | double precision            |           |          | 0.0                                  
 sales_volume_total               | double precision            |           |          | 0.0                                  
 total_units                      | integer                     |           |          | 0                                    
 current_m2_sold                  | double precision            |           |          | 0.0                                  
 sales_volume_current_sold        | double precision            |           |          | 0.0                                  
 current_units_sold               | integer                     |           |          | 0                                    
 sales_volume_to_sell             | double precision            |           |          | 0.0                                  
 next_list_acum                   | double precision            |           |          | 0.0                                  
 from_email                       | character varying           |           |          |                                      
 saved_next_list_acum             | double precision            |           |          |                                      
 settings_show_distributions_cols | boolean                     |           |          | true                                 
 settings_price_list_v2_enabled   | boolean                     |           |          | false                                
 api_token                        | character varying           |           |          |
```

Comment: Do you have a name attribute on tour project model?

Comment: Not in the model, name comes from the database

Comment: Can you post tour dB scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are referring to `association :client, factory: user` instead of `association :client, factory: :user` (`:user` should be a symbol).

This is a fairly unhelpful error message. We improved the error message a bit in https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/pull/1219, and we have an open issue to improve it more: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/1227.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Improving the error messages is great, I'm sure many people will benefit from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the class name in the factory description.

```
  FactoryBot.define do
    factory :project, class: 'Project' do
    ...
```

---

I created a factory in an existing project of mine using your same code and got the exact same error. I then changed the name of the factory to `:projector` and got the same error again. Therefore it's not a protected name problem.

My best guesses:

1) Did you make sure to migrate your test database since adding projects?

2) Are you sure that your app is connecting to the same DB that you listed?

The reason I feel this may be the cause is that if I add an attribute to my factory that doesn't on it's corresponding table, the error is the reads:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for #<Report:0x00007fc5bb065c10>
```

Thus, the factory is unable to constantize the symbol you're given it, which most likely means that it's not recognizing it as a constant/class.

Comment: Damn, I had forgotten to rollback/migrate the test database after the change i made to development's. Thanks, this answer reminded me of it.